# DTCoreText 1.6.16 nested frameworks issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, dtcoretext

I'm using the latest version of `DTCoreText` in order to fix some problems when working with `Swift`.

I've added the framework of `DTCoreText` as `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`. Also added the target dependencies explicitly in my project's build scheme.

[image: Framework dependencies]
[image: Scheme target dependencies]

But I got the linker warning about `DTFoundation`, the `DTCoreText` base framework. And also, a runtime exception raised:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DTFoundation.framework/DTFoundation
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9B4AEC86-B901-4B4C-B3F1-2460508D7FDA/WeCenterMobile.app/WeCenterMobile
  Reason: image not found
```

`DTCoreText` is a framework target, so it doesn't have embedded framework setting options. `DTFoundation` is nested in `DTCoreText`, so I can't add it directly to my main project. But `DTFoundation.framework` need to be copied to the `@rpath`.

How can I fix this? Because I'm using `git submodule` to manage the project, so I don't want to change the settings of the subproject.